# Implementing symmetry in MRCI calculation

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am running Multi Reference Configuration Interaction calculations for Aluminium Flouride molecule in its $A^1\Pi$ state interacting with Helium. For a complete Potential energy surface, I am doing the same for multiple geometries which permit interpolation to fully account for the symmetries of the interaction. My question is when I run the MRCI calculation for the linear configuration (when He approached AlF from either the side of F or Al), the MRCI energy (C2v symmetry is assumed) significantly increases (5-8 cm^-1) which makes the potential energy surface discontinous. When i force a lower symmetry in this calculations(Cs), the result are continuous with the rest of them. What I dont understand is why is there a drastic change in the interaction energy when I change the implemented symmetry from Cs to C2v (for the same configuration) i.e are MRCI basis set not invariant under symmetry change and why? I have also attached a graph that shows the difference.[image]

Comment: Did you check the compositions of the states, obtained under the two symmetries? Maybe you have converged to two different electronic states?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.